# GCD implementation in python

Tags: python, math

I am solving [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TRENDGCD/) problem in SPOJ and it states that :

> Problem statement is simple. Given A and B you need to calculate
>   S(A,B) .
>
> [image]
>
> Here, **f(n)=n, if n is square free otherwise 0. Also f(1)=1**.
>
> ***Input***
>
> The first line contains one integer **T** - denoting the number of test
>   cases.
>
> **T** lines follow each containing two integers **A,B**.
>
> ***Output***
>
> For each testcase output the value of S(A,B) mod 1000000007 in a
>   single line.
>
> Constraints
>
> ```
> `T <= 1000 
>  1 <= A,B <= 1000000`
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> Input:
> 3
> 42 18
> 35 1
> 20 25
>
>
> Output:
> 306395
> 630
> 128819
> ```

I wrote this code for this problem (if I got the the problem right) :

```
def gcd(a,b):                              #gcd(a,b)
    if b==0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b,a%b)
# print gcd(42,18)

import math
def issquarefree(n):                        #sqare free number check
    i=2
    s=i*i
    if (n==1 or n==2) or n==3:
        return True
    while s<=n:
        if n%s==0:
           i=-1
           break
        else:
            i+=1
            s=i*i
    if i==-1:return False
    else:
        return True
for i in range(int(raw_input())):           #main program 
    a,b=map(int,raw_input().split())
    g=gcd(a,b)
    sa=(a*(a+1))/2                          #see below
    sb=(b*(b+1))/2                          #see below
    gc=issquarefree(g)
    s=0
    if gc== False:
        print 0
    elif  gc==True:
          s+=sa*sb*g
    print s%1000000007
```

[here](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/BasicMath/Sum/Distributive%20law.htm)  I found that [image] so applying this to the problem # S(A,B) I wrote this as (multiplication of sum of first A and B numbers  ) multiplied by f(n) which is gcd(a,b) or 0.

But I am not getting the expected output to this problem so is my code wrong or I got the problem wrong

**my output vs expected**

```
3
35 1
42 18
20 25
630      630
926478   306395
341250   128819
```

Comment: Why are you using 'YES' and 'NO' instead of True and False

Comment: John, I think that Natecat has made a good point. You should follow common practices so that your code is more readable and understandable to fellow programmers. It will prevent others from being distracted from the small things.

Comment: John, could you please provide some examples of input and the expected output vs. what your output is?

Comment: Okay, now why are you using strings `'True'` and `'False'` instead of actual booleans?

Comment: @user2357112 i just edited the previous one with something else running in mind

Comment: @johnsmith You've implemented different algorithm. This `sa=(a*(a+1))/2` is unrelated to the formula. Plus the formula for sums does not work because of `f(...)` factor.

Comment: the f(..) factor is a constant number and I think you can write it out of the summation sign

Comment: @johnsmith Dude, `f` is not constant and thus it **cannot** be written out. Plus again: how is `sa=(a*(a+1))/2` related to the algorithm? This is a formula for `sa == 1 + 2+ ... + a`, unreleated completely.

Comment: as stated in problem  'f(n)=n, if n is square free otherwise 0. Also f(1)=1.' and n here is gcd(a,b) and gcd(a,b) is a number(constant) and so is 0 and 1 and after my code I have given a link and accordind to that  I can write sa as sum of  n numbers

Comment: @johnsmith The **function is not constant**. It doesn't mean that the value is not constant. The **function** is not constant, i.e. the value depends on `a, b` thus it **cannot** be written out. That's math, man.

Comment: 1 is a number(constant) and 0 is a number(constant), and a constant is constant, so 1 == 0? freakish is trying to help you, perhaps give his comments a little think time.

Comment: @johnsmith You are finding `f(GCD(A,B))`, not `f(GCD(a,b))`.

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks for pointing out now I see what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing out the `G(a, b) = f(gcd(a, b))` (so that you can use the cited formula) is incorrect since the function is not constant. The proper solution is this:

```
for i in range(int(raw_input())):
    A, B = map(int, raw_input().split())

    # proper algorithm
    s = 0
    for a in xrange(1, A):
        for b in xrange(1, B):
            s += a * b * G(a, b)
    print s % 1000000007
```

You obviously have to implement `G` function properly (as returning `0` or `gcd(a, b)`).

Careful analysis of `G` might give some optimization insight but it is definitely not a trivial one if any.

Here is a simple optimization:

```
import fractions

DIVISOR = 1000000007


def is_not_square_free(a):
    counter = 1
    factor = 1
    while factor < a:
        counter += 1
        factor = counter * counter
        if a % factor == 0:
            return True
    return factor == a


def F(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if is_not_square_free(n):
        return 0
    return n


_CACHE = {}
def G(a, b):
    a = a % DIVISOR
    b = b % DIVISOR
    key = (a, b) if a > b else (b, a)
    if key not in _CACHE:
        _CACHE[key] = (a * b * F(fractions.gcd(a, b))) % DIVISOR
    return _CACHE[key]


def S(A, B):
    s = 0
    for a in range(1, A+1):
        for b in range(1, B+1):
            s += G(a, b)
    return s


for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    A, B = map(int, raw_input().split())
    print(S(A, B) % DIVISOR)
```

Comment: ya! after teepeemm pointed out I got your point you are right my fault  I was getting the question wrong and you were right I had this image in mind : gcd(A,B) whereas it is gcd(a,b).Thanks for your help! I irritated you a lot unknowingly

Comment: @johnsmith No, it's my fault. I'm easily irritated. I'm still not sure what `gcd(A, B)` means (since these are sequences of numbers) but whatever. I'm glad it is finally clear how it should be.

Comment: @Teepeemm Right, I followed op's code and I've assumed that `A, B` are lists. My bad. Fixed.

Comment: @johnsmith Actually I'm pretty lucky that the way I've proposed worked. I've thought about different algorithm as well. Noone's perfect I guess. My humble apologies.

Comment: I made some small changes  and it worked for the sample inputs but on SPOJ the code gave time limit error .I think there must be  another  efficient algorithm to implement this problem because the time limit for code to run there is  0.150s-0.389s which is very small and only 7 members were able to solve this problem

Comment: @johnsmith For the given input? One way to optimize the code is to do `xrange(a, B)` in second `xrange` and then `s += 2 * a * b * G(a, b)` (because of the `a, b` symmetry). Also common values for `G` can be cached to avoid unnecessary calculations. Plus `gcd` implementation can be optimized (euclidean algorithm).

Comment: @johnsmith I've implemented those simple optimizations and added to the answer. The problem is that for `A == B == 1000000` this either takes too long or takes too much memory (or both). The issue is that for such big `A, B` doing the double `xrange` loop is heavy enough. The only way to stay in your execution range with such big numbers is to find close (i.e. independent on loops) formula for `S` function. But try to post that answer and see if it passes.

Comment: @@freakish SPOJ showed compilation error and now when I ran it on py charms it says 'module' object has no attribute 'gcd' and when I def gcd(a,b) as in my code the judge  again showed time limit error

Comment: @johnsmith Right, `math.gcd` is in Python3.5. I've changed the code to `fractions.gcd`. Also note that people who solved it actually were using C++. That might be a huge difference as it seems that the time limit is language independent so obviously Python will fail.

Comment: @@freakish I also think that C++ is making that difference what about pypy I don't know much about pypy but people say it is same as python but faster

Comment: IT again gave time limit exceed

Comment: @johnsmith While pypy is indeed faster the compilation time (yes, pypy compiles the code to machine code) takes some time. And unlike C/C++ languages there is no distinction between compilation and execution process in pypy (the so called just-in-time compilation happens during runtime). Thus I highly doubt it will produce fast enough result. Not to mention that C/C++ optimizations are far superior to anything that pypy has (due to the nature of static vs dynamic typing).

Comment: one possible optimizations that I can think of is in the square free function, instead of checking every number, only check prime number, as the upper limit is fixed at 1000000 you only need all primes number lower than 1000 and there is only 168 of those that way you reduce your worse case from 1000 check to only 168 that is a only 1/6 of the work. And as they are so few you can use the sieve of Eratosthenes to pre-generate the list of all the primes square and keep it as a global variable

Comment: @Copperfield Yeah, I've tried it and it still was too slow. I assume that the only way to really speed it up is to somehow simplify the double loop. Perhaps by starting from square free `gcd(a, b)` and then somehow generating `a, b`.

Comment: @freakish indeed, but generate the free square directly is the tricky part, there is 607925 free square number in 100000, from wich 78498 are prime and the rest 529427 are composite from which 209867 are made from 2 different primes, 206964 from 3, 92966 from 4, 18387 from 5, 1235 from 6 and finally 8 are made from 7 primes, the max prime in each case is `{2: 499979, 3: 166657, 4: 33331, 5: 4759, 6: 431, 7: 31}`, you can try to find some kind of patter in those, but that look like to much work, maybe the only real speed up is by pre-calculate those number and save then in a file

Answer (score 0):

```
def gcd(a, b):
```

#### returns greatest common divisor of a and b'''

```
return gcd(b % a, a) if a and b else max(a, b)
```

#### print test gcd should print 6,5, 7, and 9'''

```
print gcd(48,18)
print gcd(10,5)
print gcd(14,21)
print gcd (9,0)
```